Symfony command doesn't show up
I wanted to create a Symfony command in my composer package.
But when ich call bin/console it doesn't show up and when I try to call it directly I got the error that my command ist not defiend.
Did I do something wrong or is something missing?
My structure inside vendor is:
tdo
- commandeur
  - Command
    - MyCommand.php
  - Resources
    - config
     - services.xml
  composer.json

this is the composer.json:
    "name": "tdo/commandeur",
    "description": "Test Command",
    "type": "library",
    "version": "0.0.4",
    "require": {
        "symfony/console": "^6.4",
        "php": "^8.2",
        "symfony/framework-bundle": "^6.4",
        "symfony/http-foundation": "~6.4.0",
        "symfony/mime": "~6.4.0",
        "symfony/routing": "~6.4.0"
    },
    "license": "MIT",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tdo\\Commandeur\\": ""
        }
    },

this is my services.xml:
<?xml version="1.0" ?>

<container xmlns="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services"
           xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
           xsi:schemaLocation="http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services http://symfony.com/schema/dic/services/services-1.0.xsd">

    <services>
        <service id="Tdo\Commandeur\Command\MyCommand">
            <tag name="console.command"/>
        </service>
    </services>
</container>


and here ist the MyCommand.php
<?php
namespace Tdo\Commandeur\Command;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Attribute\AsCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

#[AsCommand(
    name: 'app:my-command',
    description: 'Just for testing.',
    aliases: ['app:my-command'],
    hidden: false
)]
class MyCommand extends Command
{
    protected function configure(): void
    {
        $this
            ->setName('app:my-command')
            ->setDescription('Just for testing.');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output): int
    {
        return Command::SUCCESS;
    }
}

I tried to copy my MyCommand class to another package which also uses commands and linked it in the services.xml there and that worked.
But I didn't figured out why it's working there and not for my package.

Did you clear the cache? Is there any good reason to use manual service configuration instead of autowiring? And how is this problem related to Composer or any package?

Yes, I cleared the cache multiple times. Reinstalled the package the package and restarted my docker container. No there is no reason I choose manuel service config. I'll retry with autowiring

When you use #[AsCommand] attribute, Symfony automatically registers your command. You can drop the setName call in configure method, and remove the configuration in your services.xml that way you ensure that nothing is clashing.
After that it should be working. But I don't relly know my way aroung XML configs. Is there any reason why are you not using the defaul YAML? It would be easier to troubleshoot, since it has concise syntax. There could also be problem with autowiring.
